# Setting `maxretry` of fail2ban filter to zero

Tags: security, webserver, fail2ban

Is it possible to set the `maxretry` parameter of a `fail2ban` filter to `0` so that every IP will be banned instantly? The client does not complain about this setting but it does not seem to ban IPs either. So I just wanted to ask whether this actually works.

Comment: No, I want to ban someone who already got banned before because of attempted exploitation - But then instantly and for a longer time.

Comment: For that, you should set a permanent iptable rule on his/her IP if it is ifxed

Comment: I think it's a good question.  After all, the name of the parameter is "maxretry", not "maxtry".  For me it sounds reasonable that the first try is the zeroth retry.

Answer (score 2):

If you define maxretry with 1, after first attempt fail2ban ban the ip instantly. 
Before of first attempt is impossible(logical)

Comment: In my understanding, the word maxretry suggest that it's a try after a try, thus a retry, meaning, `maxretry = 0` should and will work, banning someone/something right after his/its first try.